# What is occuring in this iterator code?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am very confused by what the following two iterators point to in the code below.

```
list<fieldT>::iterator steeperField = currentField;
list<fieldT>::iterator shallowerField = 
   activeFields.insert(currentField, *currentField);
```

If we assume that activeFields (the list these iterators pertain to) has indexes 0,1,2 (count=3), and also that currentField is presently pointing at 1. Then I imagine:

1. steeperField is set to index 1.
2. a fieldT is inserted into the list at index 1, and returns an iterator that starts at index 1.

Therefor, steeperField should be pointing to the same location as shallowField. This does *not* seem to be what's happening: shallowerField appears to point to index 2. Why?

---

`activeFields` is a parameter passed as `list<fieldT> & activeFields`. `currentField` is a parameter passed as `list<fieldT>::iterator & currentField`. `currentField` is initially started via a call to `currentField = activeFields.begin();`.

Comment: Please provide some more context. What are `steeperField`, `currentField` and `shallowerField`?

Comment: Yeah I can't quite figure this out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdd8f1df62880bef

Comment: Do you have a trace of the code you did to get it points to index 2 ?

Comment: "shallowerField appears to point to index 2" - show how you came to that deduction, because the premise immediately prior is wrong. `steeperField` is unchanged and not invalidated during this insertion. It still references the same element it did before, but now you shoved an element in front of it. If it initially referenced the 1-slot, it (`steeperField`) will now reference the 2-slot. It sounds like you're measuring with `steeperField` rather than `shallowerField`, and without code that shows what you're *really* doing, its pure speculation, so vtc unless you provide details.

Comment: I think I figured out what the OP did: assumed that list iterators point to positions in the sequence of elements, rather than the elements themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I simplify the program, [I get the results I expect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1f26b8f3c06cd91) (no assertion failures):

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using std::list;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const list<char>& l)
{
    os << '{';
    for (auto el : l)
        os << el << ',';
    os << '}';

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    list<char> l{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    list<char>::iterator insertAt { std::next(std::begin(l)) }; // 'b'

    std::cout << l << '\n';

    list<char>::iterator newEl { l.insert(insertAt, 'd') };

    std::cout << l << '\n';

    assert(std::distance(std::begin(l), insertAt) == 2);
    assert(std::distance(std::begin(l), newEl)    == 1);
}
```

This led me to believe that I'd missed something in your question, so I formulated it [as in this post](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/774dba7cd0373fd0) and deduced the issues in your question:

> Therefor, steeperField should be pointing to the same location as shallowField.

No, it shouldn't. `steeperField` is the old element which has been shuffled rightwards by one; `shallowField` is your new element. **Iterators are not fixed indexes into a container**; they link to the elements. In a linked list, that means they *follow* the element when you insert new ones before it.

> This does not seem to be what's happening: shallowerField appears to point to index 2. Why?

It does not. `shallowerField` points to index 1, as it should. `steeperField` points to index 2, also as it should.

In conclusion, **something went wrong when you made your measurements**.

Comment: I tend to conclude said-same. It deserves noting that iterators are fixed to their elements, but also the container semantics (ex. insert invalidates iterators on a vector if a resize happens, otherwise iterators before the inserted element are retained and post-element are invalidated.). Your assessment seems well-founded.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks. I made a bit of a mess of it, but I'm glad we got to the bottom of it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This solves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069712/what-mistake-did-i-make-porting-the-precise-permissive-field-of-view-algorithm-f for me, aswell. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all let discuss the funcion declaration

```
iterator insert(const_iterator position, const T& x);
```

It inserts element x before iterator position and returns iterator that refers to the inserted element.

In your example currentField; is an iterator that refers to some element in the list. *currentField is the value of the element. Now

```
activeFields.insert(currentField, *currentField)
```

inserts the same value as the value of the element refered to by currentField; before this element. In fact it propagates the value to the left relative to the currentField;.

If we assume that currentField corresponds to index 1 in the list { 0,1,2 } then after the operation the list will look as { 0,1,1, 2 } and iterator shallowerField will refer the first 1 that is it will correspond to index 1.

As for your statement

> This does not seem to be what's happening: shallowerField appears to
>   point to index 2. Why?

then the correct answer is "It seems" that is it seems to you only. You should show a simple compiled example that demonstrates the situation.

Here is an example

```
std::list<int> l = { 0, 1, 2 };

std::list<int>::const_iterator position = std::next( l.cbegin() );

std::cout << std::distance( l.cbegin(), position ) << std::endl;

std::list<int>::iterator result = l.insert( position, *position );

std::cout << std::distance( l.begin(), result ) << std::endl;
```

The ouput is

```
1
1
```

Comment: Right, so the new element should be at position 1. Why is it found at position 2?

Comment: `iterator shallowerField will refer the first 1 that is it will correspond to index 1.` Read the question. The OP said all that. The problem is [ostensibly] that it's _not_!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I have uodated my post that now refelcts your remark.

Comment: Yep looks right now - the issue seems to be that the OP has measured incorrectly.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit I have made one more change.